# PHP How to display page based on session?

Tags: php, session

I am making a website. Most of it is available to anybody visiting the site, but a small portion of it requires you to register to view. I have set up the login with Sessions. After someone logs in, it sets this:

```
$_SESSION['login'] = TRUE;
```

In one of the exclusive pages, at the top of the code before the content, I have written

```
if ($_SESSION['login'] == FALSE) {
    header("loginpage.php");
}
```

However, if somebody is not logged in, that variable does not exist, and I end up with an error. Is there any other way to check if somebody is logged in? I would like something similar to what I already have, because I don't want to have to change everything.

Comment: `if (!isset($_SESSION['login']) || $_SESSION['login'] == false) {` will get rid of the warning

Comment: #1) You are setting the value of `$_SESSION['login']` in your `if` statement, update the single `=` to double `==`. #2) Check that `$_SESSION['login']` is set and has a value of `true`.

Comment: I am using the ==, I just made a mistake typing the question. I changed it

Comment: @drew010 You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(!@$_SESSION['login'])
{
  header("location: logingpage.php");
  exit();
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to completely work. When I use that code, it only gives me a blank white page.

Comment: Make sure you have error reporting turned on.  Blank white page usually means an error stopped the execution of the page.

Comment: @MerlinWang change the header to this `header("location: logingpage.php");`

Comment: Yep, that did it. I just needed to have location: before my directory. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use isset function to determine if a variable is set and is not null.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['login']) || $_SESSION['login'] == FALSE) {
    //user isn't logged in
    header("loginpage.php");
}else{
    //user is logged
}
```

Check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a script that always runs before each page executes?  If not, this is a great place to set up any utility functions or initialize variables, like  `$_SESSION['login']`.  You can set a default false value for  `$_SESSION['login']` there.  Then you have a reliable default value, which is a good practice for a variable that's important, like this one.

You could use this to check if it's set and assign a default:

```
//Right after starting the session
if (!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
    $_SESSION['login'] = false;
}
```

If it's already got a value, this will be skipped.

You can also add an `@` before a variable when you want to use it but you can't be sure it exists.  This will suppress warnings about the existence of the variable, but I think it's better to know what the default value should be.  Sometimes it's useful to get those warnings.

Comment: Can you please explain how to set the default value? Wouldn't that change the `$_SESSION['login']` to FALSE when a logged in user visits the page?

Comment: You would want to test `if (!isset($_SESSION['login']))`.  You could do this right after you start the session.  I added a section above.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution : in the first page (or first script) of your website, create the session variable with value "false" :

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['login'] = FALSE;
?>
```

And, after some successfully logins you change the value to TRUE (as you are already doing) :

```
$_SESSION['login'] = TRUE;
```

This way the session variable will always exist, **and you will not have problems with "unset" variables**.